# Image grows even if content/compression is set to 1

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

This is what I want to create programmatically:
[image]

So that is a UIView, and inside it there is a UIImageView and a UILabel. Some notes:

- The image should always be 1:1
- The image's height should be the same as the height of the label
- If the text in the label gets wider, the view should go wider as well.
- The view's height should adapt to the label's height, so I did not have set any height constraint of the UIView.
- See this github project for an example what I want: https://github.com/Jasperav/constrains

This is my code, you can copy paste this but make sure you set a other string for the UIImageView's image:

```
class View2: UIView{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        load()

    }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    load()
}

func load(){
    let overlappingView = UIView()
    overlappingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(overlappingView)

    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "0"
    label.textColor = .white
    label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 751), for: .horizontal)
    label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999), for: .vertical)
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999), for: .vertical)
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999), for: .horizontal)

    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = UIImage(named: "Test")
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1), for: .horizontal)
    image.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1), for: .vertical)
    image.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1), for: .vertical)
    image.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1), for: .horizontal)

    overlappingView.addSubview(label)
    overlappingView.addSubview(image)

    overlappingView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    overlappingView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
    overlappingView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6).isActive = true

    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlappingView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlappingView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlappingView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true

    image.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlappingView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlappingView.leadingAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
    image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    image.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

    }
}
```

With this code, I see the image taking up the whole screen's height in 1:1 size. Why does it not respect the labels height? I have the same constrains in the interface builder, why does it not work in code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I play a little with your code and I fix it.I add some colors so you can easily see difference. If you have more questions I will help you again.

```
class View2: UIView{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        load()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        load()
    }

    func load(){
        self.backgroundColor = .green
        let overlappingView = UIView()
        overlappingView.backgroundColor = .red
        overlappingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(overlappingView)

        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "0"
        label.textColor = .black


        let image = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10))
        image.image = UIImage(named: "btn_back")
        image.tintColor = .black
        image.backgroundColor = .blue
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(1, for: .horizontal)


        overlappingView.addSubview(label)
        overlappingView.addSubview(image)

        label.sizeToFit()

        overlappingView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        overlappingView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
        overlappingView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        overlappingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: label.frame.height + 10).isActive = true

        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlappingView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlappingView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlappingView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true


        image.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlappingView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlappingView.leadingAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
        image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        image.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.leadingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I did not have set the overlappingView's height because it should adapt to the label's height. In the Interface Builder I have no problem doing that. Is it possible to not set a explicit height for the overlappingView so it adapts the label's text height?

Comment: Check for my updated decesion. Now I get label height and add 10 more px for paddings that you set below

Comment: I dont get it. In the interface builder I do not set that and it works. I uploaded my project to github, you can see that I use exactly the same constraints as in my question, but it wont work in code.

Comment: Yes your code is working, but why do I need to call label.sizeToFit() to make it work? It looks like to me something is wrong about those constrains if that function has to be called to make it work.

Comment: Another thing about your code: equalToConstant: label.frame.height + 10 returns 0 + 10, because label.frame.height is always 0 at the loading function, regardless of the input in the label.